# Cakephp 3 Cake\Cache\Engine\MemcachedEngine is not properly configured in Centos

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, cakephp-3.0

I use `memcache` and `cakephp 3` in `Centos` has error:

```
Error: [RuntimeException] Cache engine Cake\Cache\Engine\MemcachedEngine is not properly configured.
```

I installed memcache follow as:

- Install memcache and lib

  ```
     yum install memcached        
     yum install php55w-pecl-memcache
  ```
- Add config into php.ini

  ```
  extension=memcache.so
  ```

I check `info.php`, `memcache` information has displayed.

Answer (score 0):

memcached is not the same as memcache.  You have to install

```
yum install php55w-pecl-memcached
```